# Нужно найти байт, который встречается в файле максимальное число раз, и добавить его в словарь resultMap.Помогите найти ошибки

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
public static volatile Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        String s;
        while (true) {
            s = br.readLine();

            if (s.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                new ReadThread(s).start();
            }
        }
    }
    //proverka
    System.out.println(resultMap);
}

public static class ReadThread extends Thread {
    FileInputStream file;
    String s;

    public ReadThread(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //implement constructor body
        this.file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        this.s = fileName;
    }
    // implement file reading here - реализуйте чтение из файла тут

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            int count = 1;
            int max = 0;
            int b;
            while (file.available() > 0) {
                b = file.read();

                if(map.containsKey(b)){
                    count++;
                    list.add(count);
                    map.put(b,count);
                }
                else{
                    map.put(b,count);
                }
                Collections.sort(list);
                for (int i : list) {
                    if (max < i) {
                        max = i;
                    }
                     if (max > i) {
                        resultMap.put(s,b);
                    }
                }
                /*for (Integer i : map.values()) {
                    if(i > max) {
                        max = i;
                    }
                    if ( max > i ) {resultMap.put(s,b);}
                }*/
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ne nayden file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Байт? Вам нужен массив целых размером 256 элементов, так как разных байтов - всего 256. Значение прочитанного байта используйте в качестве индекса этого массива, чтобы увеличивать соответствующий элемент массива на единицу.

После чтения файла, найдите в этом массиве максимальное число. Его индекс - нужный Вам байт.

Comment: этот способ я знаю, но есть ли более приближенный к моему?

Answer (score 0):

я не знаю, зачем вам потребовалось такое количество кода еще... почитайте на досуге про принцип KISS.

ваша "многопоточность" проиграет выполнению в одном потоке, можете сами протестировать, посему в этом нет никакого смысла.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Solution {

    private static final Map<String, Integer> RESULT_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            final String fileName = sc.nextLine();
            if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)) break;
            byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName.trim()));
            IntStream.range(0, array.length).map(idx -> array[idx]).boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
                    .entrySet().stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparingLong(e -> e.getValue()))
                    .ifPresent(e -> RESULT_MAP.put(fileName, e.getKey()));
        }

        System.out.println(RESULT_MAP);
    }

}
```

Comment: зачем это все? Почему не просто цикл по байтам с записью в массив из 256 элементов?

Comment: @tym32167 и как это поможет найти байт, который встречается в каждом файле максимальное количество раз?

Comment: `int[] counts = new int[256]; for(int i=0; i<array.len; i++) { counts[array[i]]++; max = Math.Max(max, counts[array[i]]);  } return max;` - что то типа такого

Comment: многопоточность нужна по заданию, спасибо за ответы

Comment: @tym32167 не максимальный байт, а байт, который встречается максимальное количество раз

Comment: @Vlad Tsykin это не отменяет того, что эта самая многопоточность кривая. к тому же это не учебный форум, "по заданию" - это немного не сюда))

Comment: всё верно, вот этот массив `int[] counts` и хранит сколько раз какой байт встретился. Поэтому, когда встречается следующий байт, я увеличиваю нужную ячейку на единицу `counts[array[i]]++;`